# I need to sort the latitude and longitude. which is nearer to my current location

Tags: android

This is how i calculate the Distance between my list.
my code is below

```
public  void calc(){
 for(int i = 0; i < mSearchResultModelsToGetAppointments.size(); i++){
   Location newLocation = new Location("");
   newLocation.setLatitude(gpsTracker.getLatitude());
   newLocation.setLongitude(gpsTracker.getLongitude());
   if(String.valueOf(gpsTracker.getLatitude()).equalsIgnoreCase("0.0") || String.valueOf(gpsTracker.getLongitude()).equalsIgnoreCase("0.0")) {
    } else{
        Location oldLocation = new Location("");              
        oldLocation.setLatitude(mSearchResultModelUnderProcess.getLatitude());
        oldLocation.setLongitude(mSearchResultModelUnderProcess.getLongitude());   
        float distanceInMeters = newLocation.distanceTo(oldLocation)/1000;           
        if(distanceInMeters < 2820){
            getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            getAdapter().removeItem(i);
            getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
 }
}
```

This is how i display the location now.

Comment: It's not clear from the question what the problem is.

Comment: @Michael I'am getting a list of coordinates and I'am using distanceto function to calculate the distance between my current location and given coordinates. I got the result, but now i have to list them in such a way that the one which is nearer to me should come on top.

Comment: Did you find my answer is helpful, if so please vote for it and accept it

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want use any external library, I would suggest following way.

1. Create your own custom Location Class with attributes lat and lng, and additionally attribute called **distance** which measures from your current location till the point. [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/distance-2-points.html) you can find how to find distance between 2 points
2. This class should implement Comparable interface and override its *compare* function. Inside this function, you can create your own sorting logic based on distance

[here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparator-interface-java/) you can find how to use comparable interface, Let me know if you have still problem

Happy coding